# Is it possible to find through-hole, edge connector fingers?

Tags: pcb, connector, breadboard, prototyping

I would like to do a bit of prototyping and have been wanting to leverage edge connectors as it would make my layout a whole lot easier.  When using these, are you forced to get some kind of prototyping board that has built in fingers like this:
[image]

Do they sell stand-alone, through-hole fingers that can be added to a pre-existing prototyping board?  Maybe the connector and plug as a bundle?  I'm looking for something very specific... ~60pin, through-hole, ideally wire-wrap.

On a side note, if anyone knows where to even get the boards with built-in edge connectors that would be great too.  I can't really find any but that's probably because I don't know the proper search terms.

Answer (score 1):

Probably no. You may want to roll your own board for this.

Comment: Gold plating and chamfering will cost extra.

Comment: How do you do this?  You mean create it yourself based on specifications out there?

Comment: @DaveC Yes. There are drawings on how the fingers should look like.